# Combining contents of certain pages from several word documents using VBA

Tags: vba, excel, ms-word

I have a question regarding combining contents of a couple of word documents using `VBA` in `EXCEL`. This could be very simple but I am new to VBA world... Currently, I can

1. open a word document and copy all of its content
2. paste it to a combined word document
3. repeat steps 1 and 2

However, I am wondering how to skip the first page of all of the document using VBA. I tried `tempDoc.Range(Start:=2).Select`, but it did not work. Thanks for any suggestions!

```
Set objTempWord = CreateObject("Word.Application")
Set tempDoc = objWord.Documents.Open(Folderpath to Word Document)
Set objTempSelection = objTempWord.Selection
tempDoc.Range.Select
tempDoc.Range.Copy
objSelection.TypeParagraph
objSelection.Paste
objSelection.InsertBreak Type:=wdSectionBreakNextPage
tempDoc.Close
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> EDIT - Add another Word constant - change definition of Selection object

Assuming you have everything else defined
this will start at page 2 and then select eveyrthing to end of file

```
const wdGoToAbsolute = 1
const wdGoToPage =  1 
const wdGoToNext = 2 
const wdStory = 6 
const wdExtend = 1 

Set objTempWord = CreateObject("Word.Application")
Set tempDoc = objWord.Documents.Open(Folderpath to Word Document)

With tempDoc.Application
   .Selection.GoTo What:=wdGoToPage, Which:=wdGoToAbsolute, Name:="2"
   .Selection.EndKey Unit:=wdStory, Extend:=wdExtend
   .Selection.Copy
End With

objSelection.TypeParagraph
objSelection.Paste
objSelection.InsertBreak Type:=wdSectionBreakNextPage
tempDoc.Close
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I used your code but got `Run-time error 438 Object doesn't support this property or method` regarding statement `.Selection.Goto What:=wdGoToPage, which:=wdGoToAbsolute, Count:=3`

Comment: Updated code to use different object for selection and added another undefined Word constant

Comment: thanks again. Tried to modified code but got `Runtime Error 91: Object variable or with block variable not set` for the same statement...

Comment: Hmmmm.. okay one last try at your setup - I edited it again - can you add a second block of code to your original post and show exactly what you're running?

Comment: It is working now! Thanks so much! But just have a question. Where can I find definitions of variables `wdStory`, `wdGoToAbsolute `, `wdExtend `, etc.?

Comment: You can see them if you set a reference to Word - but I usually just run Debug.Print inside Word VB Editor after creating a macro. The full list is at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa211923(v=office.11).aspx

Comment: Thanks again for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Not a Word VB expert but I know the range object can accept arguments for the number of the first character and last character - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff845882.aspx. So, you need to know how many characters the number of the first character on the second sheet is and how many characters the last one on the last sheet is. Then you can use the range object - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff845882.aspx.

That said you mention Excel but don't explain why - is this a Word thing or Excel?